# Why ushort is recognized as built-in type in VSCode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

You could see what `ushort` in C++ mode in Visual Studio Code is recognized as `storage.type.built-in.cpp`:

[image: ushort has got storage.type.built-in.cpp]

I know, what `ushort` only appears as type in C#. In C++ there is no `ushort`'s (except for `USHORT` macro)
Why is this happening?

**NOTE:** I've experimented a bit more and found what `uint` is also classified as built-in.

Comment: Just in case you have some includes above the `main` function, then those may indirectly include something like `/usr/includes/sys/types.h` where `ushort` is defined. The `fstream` header includes `types.h` on my system (Linux, gcc).

Answer (score 2):

For keywords and certain types, vscode uses pattern matching to identify them, instead of verifying that those are part of any header.

The patterns used for that are defined within the file [vscode/extensions/cpp/syntaxes/cpp.tmLanguage.json](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/f74e473238aca7b79c08be761d99a0232838ca4c/extensions/cpp/syntaxes/cpp.tmLanguage.json). And one of the defined patterns there matchs `uint` as a built-in type.

You could think about opening an issue regarding this behavior on github.